# How to calculate texture coords?

Tags: c#, directx, texture-mapping

I have a program in which users can create boxes with different widths and heights.

I also have a texture (512 x 512 Pixel) which should lay on every box.

Now I have the problem that on 90x90 Box (`Mesh.Box`) i can lay the texture 4x4 times.

So I thought that i could use the ratio 4/90 so texture the boxes. But that does not work[image]

The box has a width by 28.723 and a height by 56.43661

I use the following code to calculate the texture coords:

```
float tex_coords_w = 4.0f / 90;
float tex_coords_h = 4.0f / 90;

mesh = Mesh.Box(d3dDevice, width, height, 0);

        Mesh tempMesh = mesh.Clone(mesh.Options.Value, VertexFormats.PositionNormal | VertexFormats.Texture1, d3dDevice);
        CustomVertex.PositionNormalTextured[] vertData = (CustomVertex.PositionNormalTextured[])tempMesh.VertexBuffer.Lock(0, typeof(CustomVertex.PositionNormalTextured), LockFlags.None, tempMesh.NumberVertices);
        for (int i = vertData.Length / 2; i < vertData.Length; i += 4)
        {
            vertData[i + 1].Tu = Convert.ToSingle(i) + 0.0f;
            vertData[i + 1].Tv = Convert.ToSingle(i) + 0.0f;
            vertData[i + 2].Tu = Convert.ToSingle(i) + tex_coords_w * width;
            vertData[i + 2].Tv = Convert.ToSingle(i) + 0.0f;
            vertData[i + 3].Tu = Convert.ToSingle(i) + tex_coords_w * width;
            vertData[i + 3].Tv = Convert.ToSingle(i) + tex_coords_h * height;
            vertData[i + 0].Tu = Convert.ToSingle(i) + 0.0f;
            vertData[i + 0].Tv = Convert.ToSingle(i) + tex_coords_h * height;
        }
        tempMesh.VertexBuffer.Unlock();



        mesh.Dispose();
        mesh = tempMesh;
```

Can someone help me please?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to repeat the texture n times on each face.

1. Set the texture addressing mode to the WRAP mode
2. Set the texture coordinates as below for each face of the box.

   ```
       A(0, 0)                    B(n, 0)
              -------------------
              |                 |
              |                 |
              |                 |
              |                 |
              |                 |
              |                 |
              |                 |
       D(0, n) ------------------- C(n, n)
   ```

Here is the code example, I am using native DirectX, take vertex B for example, it's position is (5.0, 5.0, 0), and the texture coordinate is(0, 4.0f), so the texture repeat 4 times across u direction.

```
// Vertex layout
struct Vertex
{
    float x, y, z ; // Position
    float u, v ;    // Texture coordinates
};

Vertex FrontFace[] = 
{
    {-5.0f,  5.0f, 0,    0,    0},  // Vertex A
    { 5.0f,  5.0f, 0, 4.0f,    0},  // B
    { 5.0f, -5.0f, 0, 4.0f, 4.0f},  // C
    { 5.0f, -5.0f, 0, 4.0f,    0},  // D
} ;
```

Typically, the u- and v-texture coordinates that you assign to a vertex are in the range of 0.0 to 1.0 inclusive. However, by assigning texture coordinates outside that range, you can create certain special texturing effects.

see [Texture Addressing Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details. this is for native DirectX, but you can simply apply it in C#.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. What does that mean for my for-loop? Can you give me an example for this? Thanks

Comment: suppose vertData[0] starts from the top-left corner of the face, and vertData[123] followed in clockwise order, you can try the following code.`vertData[0].Tu = 0; 
vertData[0].Tv = 0;
vertData[1].Tu = 1; 
vertData[1].Tv = 0;
vertData[2].Tu = 1; 
vertData[2].Tv = 1;
vertData[3].Tu = 0; 
vertData[3].Tv = 1;`